# Facebook Like button and friends newsfeed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I am working on new video website, and I want to make social plugins below every video. If the user wants, he will click the like button and the video picture and its description will appear on the user wall. But I have a problem- It does appear on his wall, but not on friends newsfeed.
I have seen couple of websites doing same thing with social plugins and they got it wokring to appear on friends newsfeed.
What do I need to do in order to make that working properly? Is my website need to be added manually to "approved" websites or somthing similer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already got the OpenGraph meta tags? You can get your customized Facebook Plugins code and meta tags on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Good luck!

Comment: I didnt put tags because I cant, its Wordpress, insted of it I am using plugin. There is a post with title,image and description, but it dont appear on the friends newsfeed. I have tried to make regular website (without Wordpress), but after few likes it dont appear on friends newsfeed any more.

Comment: Just Facebook trying to stop spam, and you will always be able to put the tags, Wordpress has it's own editor